# xfce4: setting a region for screenshot in terminal and trigger by keyboard shortcut

Tags: xfce, screenshot

Is there any way to set a certain region up for screenshot beforehand?

Like:

```
xfce4-screenshooter -r 700,200:1300:800 -c
```

So I don't need to select the area every time...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, it's not specified in the manual:

```
-r, --region
    Select  a  region  to  be  captured by clicking a point of the screen without releasing the mouse button, dragging your mouse to the
    other corner of the region, and releasing the mouse button.
```

---

The only program I could find that allows you to that is `scrot`:

```
sudo apt install scrot
```

Then you can run the command:

```
scrot -a 200,200,200,200 yourfile.png
```

The numbers correpond to `x` axis, `y` axis, `width`, and `height`:

```
-a, --autoselect
  Non-interactively choose a rectangle of x,y,w,h.
```